# Creating a Search Interface to present results in a listview in the same activity using searchview widget on android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter, searchview

I am new to android development and I am trying to create a Search Interface to present results in a listview in the same activity using the search widget "SearchView". I have already reviewed the android documentation http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchableConfiguration but I have followed all the steps and configuration to achieve the basics on implementing adding the search widget on the actionbar and so on and so forth, however the documentation does not provide info on how to query the data to be presented on a listview. Can anyone please  guide me through a complete tutorial on how to do this. Thank you.

This is a print screen of what I would like to achieve: [image]

Comment: Use a FilterQueryProvider - if your list is backed by a DB

Comment: Hi Skynet... the list is backed by just an array that will contain several items, not a DB by now. How can I go about doing what I want?

Comment: So are you using an Array Adapter? Its pretty easy extending `Filter` check [this](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-custom-layout-filter.html)

Comment: Yes, Array Adapter... do you have an example that you can show me or a link of a tutorial... I am new to this.

Comment: I saw the example you sent me on the link but I want to be able to use the Search Widget in the actionbar, not an EditText... how can I reference the EditText in the actionbar

Comment: SearchView is a View of one sort at the end, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562269/filtering-a-listview-with-searchview-and-custom-adapter)

Answer (score 1):

you can use TextWatcher for this

eg.

```
ur_edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
{
//Do your search algorithm here
}

@Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    SearchView search;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        search=(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
        search.setQueryHint("SearchView");

        //*** setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener ***
        search.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(hasFocus),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

        //*** setOnQueryTextListener ***
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), query, 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), newText,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }    
}
```

Comment: It does not seem to work. I am extending to ListActivity. any reference on how to achieve this while using ListActivity?

Comment: what errors you getting..why to use listactivity,,just try it with activity